# Perforated T-Steel Profile

Tags: modifiers

[image]I'm actually a bloody amateur, but I'm here to fix this and learn "How to Pro".
I'm working on a spaceship project and I want to make it look like you're building it in real life. Part by part. That said, I need a skeleton to mount the rest of on it. I want to use T-steel profiles with holes. Now my Question.
Is it better to create a T-steel profile Object (3d), drill holes in it using the Boolean function and somehow "Array modify" it along a path, OR would it be better and easier to create a Bezier circle and use the "bevel and taper" function to bring it into the T Steel shape and after that modify it with the array modifier to align Holes along the bezier circle?
Because I want a solid ring object that I can use as a single Skelton rib.

Comment: If you really want to be a pro, avoid booleans. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: ok, thanks for that advice. ^^

...everyone started at some point :-)

Answer (score 3):

It would be counter productive to use boolean in your case, you'd better create your shape and array it along a curve, like that:

- Create a plane and ceate some edge loops:

[image]

- Cut a hole, select the edge loop, extrude inwards, make a circle with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

- Extrude up:

[image]
[image]

- Give your object an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier. To get nice round holes you'll need to give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, then you'll need to add some edge loops to sharp the edges:

[image]

Comment: this one here is interesting... very interesting. 1st i wanna thank all u guys and ladys (?) for this kind help. Nice to have such a great Communtiy in the back. I read all of the Comments and all of the Advices. I'll work something out based on all of these great tips and let u all know what the result of it is. 

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call myself a 'pro'....

It's not clear exactly what shape you're looking for: this example aims to cover a 'kit' of possible methods for a range of perforated bars, some of which you may not need. It's a 90 degree I-bar bracket, curved, tapered, and perforated. The first thing to notice is that the job is essentially flat; all we have to do is get the topology OK in 2D. The rest is extrusions.

[image]

1. We're going for 5 holes, so we subdivide a plane into 10 regions (9 cuts). We put the origin at center of the left edge, and have its object X along its length.
2. The holes are going to get smaller towards the thin end, so the regions will have to be closer there. With the pivot at the left edge, and the left edge selected, under Proportional Editing > *Linear* falloff, scale the plane along its length. At any stage, you can select all, and scale back to bring the overall length back to where you want it.
3. Now we can give the  plane a *Simple Deform > Taper* modifier, followed by a *Simple Deform > Bend* modifier. You're still free to adjust the segments, and overall length. We're aiming for roughly square groups of 4 faces.
4. Once we're satisfied with the inner shape, we can <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the top and bottom boundaries, right-click to drop the extrusions in place, and then scale in the up-down axis. This is to generate surplus material we  can outset into.

[image]

5. The bracket is tapered, the I-section is not, so we have to apply the modifiers. Now you can <kbd>I</kbd> inset the blue region with *Outset* checked, to get the even border we need.
6. Discard the excess (white) material..
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Dissolve every other inner radius,or vertex, leaving 8-vertex inner faces..
8. ..which we can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> menu > *Poke* to give 8-poles at their centers.

[image]

9. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel the pole-vertices, with *Percentage* checked, to give proportionate inner faces
10. Use the shipped add-on *Loop Tools > Circle > (Best Fit)* to turn them into circles. If your Transform Center is set to *Individual Origins*, you can scale / rotate the circles after creation
11. Delete the holes and <kbd>E</kbd> extrude all faces. Further <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *> Along Normals* the border faces to give the I-section.
12. Give everything a *Bevel* modifier by angle,(segments 2, profile 1?) to put in holding loops, and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier

[image]

**TL;DR**.. check @moonboots' answer :D

Comment: im very curious which method will fit my needs better....
 thanks for this idea 